# JAVA - Use synchronized list thread in main

Tags: java, multithreading, list

i have a method in a class for create Thread and i need to use the List of Thread.

```
public class LocalClient {

   /*
   *   Some Stuff
   */
   LocalClientThread thr;

   public LocalClient(){

        this.setHotes();

        for(InetAddress i : thr.getNetwork()) 
           System.out.println(i.getHostAddress()); //no error but write nothing.


    }
    public void setHotes(){

      thr = new LocalClientThread(c);
      Thread t = new Thread(thr);
      t.start();

}
```

And my Thread

```
public class LocalClientThread extends Thread {

     List<InetAddress> network = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<InetAddress>());

    DatagramSocket c;

    public LocalClientThread(DatagramSocket c){
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
          while(true){

              /* Some Stuff
              */

              network.add(receivePacket.getAddress());       
          }  
        }

    }
    /**
     * @return the network
     */
    public List<InetAddress> getNetwork() {
        return network;

    }
}
```

Actually my Thread adds all the received adresse in the List correctly.

But i want to use the list when thread finishes to add all of the addresses...
Any ideas ?

Comment: Avoid "public class LocalClientThread extends Thread" better: "public LocalClient implements Runable"

Answer (score 1):

Use [Thread.join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) in order to wait for your thread to end, then call getNetwork() in order to access the list your Thread just filled.

In your code this would look something like:

```
thr = new LocalClientThread(c);
Thread t = new Thread(thr);
t.start();
t.join(); // waits for Thread t to come to end
List<InetAddress> collectedAddresses = thr.getNetwork();
```

Comment: I've tried this but i don't know how i can say to my thread to end...
i can't do `this.stop()` in my thread class...

Comment: If you want to terminate your thread from outside do something like `while(keepRunning) {}` in your run method. This way you can set the volatile boolean variable keepRunning to false from outside and the thread will come to an end.